# Is possible to create clickable TubeVisual3D in a HelixToolKit WPF project?

Tags: wpf, clickable, helix-3d-toolkit

What would be the correct way to create a TubeVisual3D that could have associated events, especially user interaction events, like mouse clicks?

Using HelixToolKit in a WPF C# project.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if it was the best choice, but I implemented a transparent Mesh constructed with several cylinder with a path equal to the TubeVisual3D element that I could click on. This means that the user will see a TubeVisual3D, but he clicks on a transparent cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

Below I have outlined a different approach that worked for me.
I'd recommend looking at the UIElement3D class.[UIElement3D class reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement3d(v=vs.100).aspx)

Here we go.

- Create a class extending UIElement3D.
- Create the tube object in the constructor and assign it to the Visual3DModel member.
- Override the event handler that suits your needs.

Here's an example.

```
using System.Windows.Media;    
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

public InteractiveTubeVisual3D : UIElement3D
{
   public InteractiveTubeVisual3D( List<Point3D>paths, double tubeDiameter = 0.55)
   {
        int thetaDiv = 12;
        Material material = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial( Colors.Crimson );

        MeshBuilder meshBuilder = new MeshBuilder();
        meshBuilder.AddTube(paths, tubeDiameter, thetaDiv, false);

        GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D( meshBuilder.ToMesh(), material);
        Visual3DModel = model;
   }

   protected override void OnMouseDown( MouseButtonEventArgs Event )
   {
       base.OnMouseDown( Event );
       //change the color of the tube when left mouse clicked, revert back on right mouse clicked
       if ( Event.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed )
       {
           GeometryModel3D
               tube = Visual3DModel as GeometryModel3D;
               tube.Material = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial( Colors.CornflowerBlue );
       }
       else if ( Event.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed )
       {
           GeometryModel3D
               tube = Visual3DModel as GeometryModel3D;
               tube.Material = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial( Colors.Crimson );
       }

       Event.Handled = true;
   }

}
```

The next steps illustrates how to add it to your scene.

- Create a ContainerUIElemnt3D.[ContainerUIElement3D class ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.containeruielement3d(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Add the tube to the ContainerUIElement3D as a child.
- Add the ContainerUIElement3D object as a child of the Helix Viewport.

Sample Program

```
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow( )
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ContainerUIElement3D container = new ContainerUIElement3D();

        List<Point3D> paths = CreatePath(); // pass in you tubes points. 

        InteractiveTubeVisual3D tube = new InteractiveTubeVisual3D(paths);
        container.Children.Add(tube);

        HelixViewPort.Children.Add(container);
    }
}
```

HelixViewPort is an x:Name ref from the XAML

```
<h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="HelixViewPort" >
    <h:DefaultLights/>
</h:HelixViewport3D>
```

Hope it helps :). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.  You have to use a hit test to figure out if the mouse click is on your TubeVisual3D, once you know this you can do whatever action you desire. This has to be done via the mouse click event...